# Why does the same inequality give different answers?

Tags: logarithms

$\left(\log _2\left(x\right)-2\right)\left(\log _2\left(x\right)+1\right)<0$

has a solution $\frac{1}{2}<x<4$

But when we take the second part alone that is

$\left(\log _2\left(x\right)+1\right)<0$

it gives a solution $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ why is $x>\frac{1}{2}$ in the first case but $x<\frac{1}{2}$ in the second case?

Comment: you should take the intersection of each set of values

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need *exactly one* of $\log_2(x) -2$ and $\log_2(x) + 1$ to be negative. The problem reduces to solving the **simultaneous** inequalities:

$$\log_2(x) -2 <0 \text{ and } \log_2(x) + 1>0$$

and

$$\log_2(x) -2 >0 \text{ and }\log_2(x) + 1<0$$

to get two solution sets.

So to answer your question, you're correct that $\log_2(x) +1 <0$ when $0<x<\frac12$, but in this region, we also have $\log_2(x) -2 <0$, so overall the inequality is positive.